# Why is Amazon Redshift truncating the precision of this JSON float data?

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I've found that Amazon Redshift is truncating the precision of floating point numbers to a VERY low precision (6 places). Is there any way around this?

Example:

```
SELECT
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT('{"a":123456789.5555555, "b":123456789.0}', 'a')::float,
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT('{"a":123456789.5555555, "b":123456789.0}', 'b')::float;
```

Gives:

```
 json_extract_path_text | json_extract_path_text 
------------------------+------------------------
              123457000 |              123457000
(1 row)
```

Compare that to integers:

```
SELECT
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT('{"a":123456789, "b":123456789}', 'a')::float,
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT('{"a":123456789, "b":123456789}', 'b')::float;
```

Which results in:

```
 json_extract_path_text | json_extract_path_text 
------------------------+------------------------
              123456789 |              123456789
(1 row)
```

It seems like float should have more precision, not less!!!

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Why do you need such precision in an analytical database? Anyway you are going to do AVG and other statistical functions that don't need such high precision.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the FLOAT precision of Redshift itself, but the precision of the parsed JSON number. If we query the JSON without doing any conversion…

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT('{"a":123456789.5555555}', 'a');
```

…which results in this VARCHAR value:

```
"1.23457e+08"
```

Therefore any subsequent conversion to FLOAT can only work with this already inaccurate value.

A workaround would be to store the numbers inside the JSON as string…

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT('{"a":"123456789.5555555"}', 'a')::float;
↓
123456789.55555549
```

If even higher precision is required, a conversion to the [DECIMAL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html#r_Numeric_types201-decimal-or-numeric-type) datatype could be used…

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT('{"a":"123456789.5555555", "b":123456789.0}', 'a')::decimal(20, 10)
↓
123456789.5555555000
```

---

Alternatively you could also implement a [User-Defined Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) where you do the JSON parsing yourself with higher precision.